# Resolving and initializing view models created at runtime with a DI container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Our application is similar to an IDE. The user can open files (coming from a DB), and then use the application's various aspects to edit that file. The application can have multiple tabs with different files open.
We use Simple Injector with WPF and MVVM. Bootstrapping the initial application works fine and can be resolved from the container. However, we're not sure on the DI design that handles the runtime data (the file to be opened).
We essentially have something like this:

```cs
public class MainWindowVm : ObservableRecepient
{
    public MainWindowVm(IQueryProcessor queryProcessor, IDependency dep){ /*...*/}
    
    public ObservableCollection<FileVm> OpenFiles { get; } = new();
    
    // Called from a message dispatched from another component.
    public void OpenFile(FileDomainModel model)
    {
        // Oh no, FileVm should not be manually new'ed
        var fileVm = new FileVm(model, queryProcessor, dep);
        
        // Alternative?
        var fileVm = // Where could FileVm come from?
        fileVm.Model = model; // Property Injection
        fileVm.SetModel(model); // or Method injection
        
        OpenFiles.Add(fileVm);
        
        //...   
    }
}
```

There are obviously more injectable dependencies in our real application.

Now, I have extensively searched, and most proposed solutions have serious drawbacks, such as injecting the container outside the composition root or adding a service locator. Also, the model can't really "flow" exclusively via methods through the applications — the view models are bound to views and as such have properties the views bind to.

One possible solution we're eying is using the messenger system of the MVVM toolkit. The view models can get instantiated by the container (good), and then receive a message when a file is opened to set their properties for binding internally (...good?). Still, the question remains how new view models are instantiated at runtime, since every time a file is opened, we need a new set of VMs.

If the answer is "you need to change your design", this is also valid and I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MVVM model I'm currently working on (WPF, Caliburn Micro, Simple Injector) we hide the management, creation and opening of screens behind an abstraction.

In your example, you show the use of an `IQueryProcessor` abstraction. I assume this abstraction is similar to what I described years ago [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/queries/). Our application uses this abstraction extensively. For opening screens, we use an abstraction that is very similar to `IQueryProcessor`, i.e. the opening of screens is done through messages:

- We define a message that describes the runtime information important for that screen to function, similar to the messages for [commands](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/commands/) and [queries](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/queries/)
- We create a 'handler' for that message, which is the underlying view model
- We have one central mediator that depends on the Container and allows dispatching the incoming message to the underlying view model, similar to the implementation of `IQueryProcessor` in your question.

I won't be very specific here, because I think giving any concrete examples of the implementation in our application would only push you into a certain direction, while I think it's good to construct these abstractions and implementations from the needs of your specific application.

With a construct like this, however, you would be able to reduce the `MainWindowVm` to something like this:

```cs
public class MainWindowVm : ObservableRecepient
{
    public MainWindowVm(
        IQueryProcessor queries,
        IModelDialogDispatcher dialogs, // The new abstraction
        IDependency dep){ /*...*/}
    
    public ObservableCollection<string> OpenFiles { get; } = new();
    
    public void OpenFile(FileDomainModel model)
    {
        var message = new SelectFile(model); // the request message
        SelectFileResponse response = dialogs.Open(message);

        OpenFiles.AddRange(response.SelectedFiles);
    }
}
```

But that said, this message-based architecture works very well in our case to disconnect view models from each other and allow the DI infrastructure to create view models.

Comment: Thank you, Steven, I'd hoped you'd answer :) We use indeed the Command/Query-architecture from your blog/book. In your sample, the `OpenFiles` are now strings, does that mean that the VMs don't know each other at all, or was this just a simplification? `OpenFiles` is bound to a `TabControl` in our case, and builds the contents of the tabs automatically via `DataTemplates`. Your suggestion, combined with a factory function as part of composition root (as Guru Stron in the other answer suggested), seems like a good solution, however.

Comment: The use of strings in my answer is indeed a simplification. Although you could return anything you want from the VM, my preference is to only return objects that are data centric; part of the message, similar to what you'll do with commands and queries. I find that model easier to reason about, and as a bonus, it gives high isolation between VMs.

Answer (score 1):

> such as injecting the container

It depends where are you injecting it. This particular case usually is solved by implementing a factory pattern and I would argue that this is more than ok to inject what is needed into the factory. Not very familiar with the Simple Injector but with .NET Core build-in DI quite standard approach with `Func`-based factory can look as simple as:

```cs
services.AddScoped<Func<FileDomainModel, FileVm>>(serviceProvider => fdm =>
    new FileVm(
        model, 
        serviceProvider.GetService<IQueryProcessor>(), 
        serviceProvider.GetService<IDependency>()));
```

And then inject `Func<FileDomainModel, FileVm>` where needed.

Also this can be simplified a bit by introducing something like `FileVmDeps` class which will encapsulate all the required dependencies.

Note that if `FileVm` is disposable then at least with the build-in DI the responsibility to dispose it is on the client invoking the factory (or whoever becomes the owner of the lifetime of the instance).

Comment: This is a nice idea, I'd never come up with that myself. I think this would work well in conjunction with Steven's answer.